# display:none does not show other div

Tags: html, css

I have a code that is formatted like this:

```
<div id = "test" class = "invisible">
    <!--I want to hide this!-->
    %%GLOBAL_ProductDescription%%
</div>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    //Takes the info within the div above and manipulates some information
    var desc = $('#test').html();

    //Put edits to new_desc
    $(document).ready(function() {
         document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = new_desc;
    });
</script>

<div class = "stuff" id = "product">
    <a id = "info"><!--receive info from script here--></a>
</div>
```

The code works properly in terms of the last div displaying the information and formatting that I want to have. The problem now is: the page is displaying the original information plus the edited one in the bottom. Whenever I try to *hide* the first div, everything else goes away!

I would manipulate the data by just assigning the contents of the global variable into my Javascript variable but that it sort of out of the picture right now. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong and why hiding this one div completely gets rid of all the other information in the page?

Note: When I type some gibberish at the beginning of the code, it shows even though there's a display:none. If I put it anywhere below that line, it does not show either.

Comment: It doesn't have an id on it, so if you are hiding all $('div') 's then it makes sense.  Impossible to tell without the code....

Comment: @briansol Sorry for the confusion. The last div has its own class and id as well.

Comment: It sounds like the HTML code is incorrect, so that the first div actually doesn't end before the script but encompasses the entire page. What does it contain?

Comment: Have you... validated your entire HTML first? In case of broken HTML, browsers may decide your `id=test` node isn't finished yet.

Comment: @Guffa I checked that over and over again too. The real code for the first div is this: <div id = "description" class = "invisible">%%GLOBAL_ProductDesc%%</div>

Comment: @Wrikken Yes. Unless I'm completely blind, it should be right.. :(

Comment: Your javascript code uses both "desc" and "new_desc" - which is it really?

Comment: @Pointy You take in the info in desc. new_desc carries the manipulated information.

Comment: Where's the CSS?  What is the *actual* contents of that `<div>` that's not successfully being hidden?

Comment: When you look at the cannot-be-hidden `<div>` in the browser DOM inspector, what do you see?

Comment: It works fine. Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c20Luy5s/)

Comment: @Pointy It contains the product description. That product description has its own html formatting inside it but it does not work with this new platform that we're using. I put the description (%%GLOBAL_ProductDesc%%) inside because I have no idea how to automatically assign the contents of the product description like so: var desc = $("something-here").html();... :( The only CSS that that div is using is: .invisible { display:none; }

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi I hope it works as great as that... but for some reason it won't. I'm really lost as to why.

Comment: @Rezylience: The code you posted works fine, as you've seen yourself. Problem lies somewhere else. Can you post your whole code here: https://justpaste.it/ and comment the link here.

Comment: Look, this is something you need to work out in your very own browser using the DOM inspector.  Through that you can see exactly the way browser decided how to interpret your HTML, and you can see the CSS rules that are (and aren't) in effect for any element. From what you've posted, nobody can help you.

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi This is the code: http://justpaste.it/gxmw Thanks!

Comment: Or try this: Remove the `invisible` class from your CSS. and hide your `div` like this `$('#test').hide();`

Comment: @Pointy I've gone back and forth with this for days now in the ways I know how and I could not see where I have gone wrong. I apologize for wasting your time. I figured I should ask around to see if I can get some help from those of you who know more than I do. I'll keep looking and thanks for your help.

Comment: Well what have you found from using the DOM inspector? When you click on the `<div>` you want to hide, what does the DOM inspector tell you? When you look at the DOM, does the contents of that `<div>` seem correct? You're the only one who can do that work.

Comment: And it would be much more useful (MUCH more useful) to see the code as it looks when you do a "View Source" in the browser.

Comment: Also if you want to "sneak" text into an HTML document the way to do it is to use a `<script type="text/html">` tag - the browser won't show that by default and the nature of the markup inside (so long as it doesn't contain other `</script>` closing tags) absolutely doesn't matter.

Comment: This [Update](http://jsfiddle.net/c20Luy5s/3/)

Comment: @Pointy For some reason it's pushing the script and second div inside another div within the product description formatting. So essentially, the script and second div are under the first one and that's probably why it's hiding it. I am not sure why they would be in there in terms of the code though...

Comment: I'm not sure either, because *you haven't posted what the code looks like when you do a "View Source" from the browser.* However the tools you've got should make it possible to determine where things are going wrong.

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi It still does the same thing... Probably because of what I mentioned above. I have to find out why it's appearing on that part of the code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Pointy http://snag.gy/I0881.jpg The highlighted ones are the divs and script that I talked about in the original post.

Comment: Without checking what's actually _inside_ that `%%GLOBAL_ProductDesc%%` when things go wrong... this comment thread is pretty useless. Have you validated the _content_ that's in there?

Comment: @Wrikken The content changes per product and is being used in a platform where it's performing well so I _assumed_ it was formatted properly. Big mistake! Anyway, I got my temporary fix for now. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget the for a lot of languages there are libraries available that will fix your broken html(snippets). I wouldn't overwrite them without checking, but you could set up a quick test fixing the content, and if you're pleased after testing a lot / most of them, you could go for the bulk update (but be aware that the mechanism that saves broken HTML in there should be fixed as well).

Answer (score 0):

The content changes per product. There may have been some divs in there that weren't closed properly and that's why it's pushing the latter part of the code somewhere inside %%GLOBAL_ProductDesc%%. I did not know it could behave like that so I overlooked that part in my check.

I can't really go ahead and bulk edit about 4000 products such that the HTML in there is correct so I inserted 4 s before the start of the script and everything looks good. I know this may not be the most robust answer to the question but it works for now. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Use notepad++ or something that will color code your html and you'll be able to see unterminated definitions better.